# ExtJS Unmask after data load

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using a JSONStore in ExtJS and loading data by using setting the URL config and then calling the load method, is there anyway i can unmask the form only once the data is loaded. At the moment it unmasks after the load method which doesn't work since the load is async. But what i want to do is only unmask after the async operation has completed. Any Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Insert your code to hide the mask in the callback of the load function.

```
store.load({
params: { your params },
callback: function(r, options, success) {
    // Checks to make sure the response was returned
    if(success == true) {
        // Logic to ensure valid data returned
        if (r.status == true) {     
            mask.hide();
        }

        else {
            ...
        }
    }

    else {
        ...
    }
}
```

});

Comment: where does the `mask` variable come from?